# How to combine two csv documents to a figure with dirffrent timespan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

compare temperatures in two places with different timespan

temperature data in death_valley is from 2014.7.1-2014.12.29
while
data in sitka is from 2014.1.1-2014.12.29

```
dates=[]
for row in reader_death_valley:
    current_date=datetime.strptime(row[0],'%Y-%m-%d')
    dates.append(current_date)
```

and I don't know how to set date as x_axis

```
plt.plot(dates,highs_death_valley,c='red')
plt.plot(dates,highs_sitka,c='blue')
```

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (313,) and (0,)

Comment: I copied data in sitka from 7.1-12.29 by Excel and created a new spreadsheet, but the error is still  x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (313,) and (0,)